# Disallow pop segue to certain class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I've got a `UINavigationController` that can pop to multiple VC's. I want to disallow the 'slide to pop' slide animation if the VC to pop to is of a certain class. How do I do that?

Disabling the slide animation for the entire navigationcontroller can be done like this:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

But I want that only to be true if the destination is of a certain class.

Comment: Hi Im sorry I need some more details to understand what you want... You want want to disable the animation of a UINavigationControllers pop method? Or do you want to disable even the pop itself?

Comment: @Neo added some explanation. Do you understand it better now?

Comment: Yes, but your problems already solved right? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tried this but the following should work:

`UINavigationController` has the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` property.

In the `viewDidAppear` method of the view controller that you don't want to allow the "slide to pop", do:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = NO;
```

Then in the same view controller's `viewDidDisappear` method, call:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.enabled = YES;
```

Comment: Of course! How could I not have seen that. Great, simple answer :)